# Make a project with nuxt3.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I hope you are well
I installed nuxt 3 and it installed successfully but when I run it gives me an error.
I run my default code but it returns an error
[image: The image of error is in this link]

[image: The image of terminal error is in this link]

[image: The second image of terminal error is in this link]

Comment: Please format the error(s) as code rather than posting images

Comment: Could you see the picture? I sent the image of terminal error too @sebtheiler

Comment: I don't have it under the hand but there was already a question like that. It's a windows issue mainly. Give a search with the error you shared in the screenshots.